# Custom initializers, why use Date() instead of dateCreated?

Tags: swift

I am learning about initializing a class for UITableView and UITableViewController topic. Why in the code below we use Date() instead of dateCreated? Thank you.

```
class Item {
    var name: String
    var valueInDollars: Int
    var serialNumber: String?
    let dateCreated: Date

    init(name: String, serialNumber: String?, valueInDollars: Int) {
       self.name = name
       self.valueInDollars = valueInDollars
       self.serialNumber = serialNumber
       self.dateCreated = Date()
}
```

}

Comment: The result of 'Date()' *is assigned to* the `dateCreated` member.

Comment: `self.something`, that's the variable of the intance, `something`, that's just the parameter of the method. If you have issue, write `init(pName: String, pSerialNumber: String?, pValueInDollars: Int)`, for "parameterVariable", and it should be later `self.name = pName` etc. You don't have a date parameter, so by default, set it to now (`Date()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the `dateCreated` property is actually supposed to be a **constant**. The value is assigned when the instance is created and will never be modified.

So the more practical approach is

```
class Item {
    var name: String
    var serialNumber: String?
    var valueInDollars: Int
    let dateCreated = Date()

    init(name: String, serialNumber: String?, valueInDollars: Int) {
       self.name = name
       self.serialNumber = serialNumber
       self.valueInDollars = valueInDollars
    }
}
```

According to the rules all properties must be initialized when an instance is created. The default values of `name`, `valueInDollars` and `serialNumber` are assigned in the `init` method and `dateCreated` is being initialized directly.

In most cases a `struct` is sufficient, the `init` method can be omitted

```
struct Item {
    var name: String
    var serialNumber: String?
    var valueInDollars: Int
    let dateCreated = Date()
}
```

If the other struct member are constants, too, replace `var` with `let`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following properties:

- `self.name`
- `self.valueInDollars`
- `self.serialNumber`
- `self.dateCreated`

These are declared inside your `Item` class, like so:

```
class Item {

    /// the following 4 properties
    var name: String
    var valueInDollars: Int
    var serialNumber: String?
    var dateCreated: Date
```

Your **initializer**, which is...

```
init(name: String, serialNumber: String?, valueInDollars: Int) {
```

... has the purpose of *initializing* all of those 4 properties.

Inside your initializer, that is exactly what you are doing:

```
self.name = name /// set self.name to name
self.valueInDollars = valueInDollars /// set self.valueInDollars to valueInDollars
self.serialNumber = serialNumber /// set self.serialNumber to serialNumber
self.dateCreated = Date() /// /// set self.name to Date()
```

Note the `self.` That is because the argument labels of your initializer are named the same as the properties.

So why is the last property, `self.dateCreated`, assigned to `Date()`?

Take a look at your initializer's argument labels again:

```
init(name: String, serialNumber: String?, valueInDollars: Int) {
```

There is only `name`, `serialNumber`, and `valueInDollars`. There is no argument label that should set `self.dateCreated`, so instead you just made a new `Date()`.

However, you *could* add one if you want:

```
init(name: String, serialNumber: String?, valueInDollars: Int, someDateCreated: Date) {
```

Then set `self.dateCreated` to `someDateCreated`:

```
self.name = name /// set self.name to name
self.valueInDollars = valueInDollars /// set self.valueInDollars to valueInDollars
self.serialNumber = serialNumber /// set self.serialNumber to serialNumber
self.dateCreated = someDateCreated /// set self.name to someDateCreated
```

The names of the argument labels don't need to match the names of the properties, as shown in `someDateCreated`. To differentiate, you use the `self.`

#### TL;DR

The compiler doesn't care how you initialize your properties. The only thing it cares about is that **all of them are initialized**.

For example, you could do this:

```
init() { /// no argument labels
    self.name = "Some random name"
    self.valueInDollars = 1234
    self.serialNumber = "ABCDEFG"
    self.dateCreated = Date()
}
```

... or this:

```
init(name: String, serialNumber: String?) {
    self.name = name /// set self.name to name
    self.valueInDollars = 1234
    self.serialNumber = serialNumber /// set self.serialNumber to serialNumber
    self.dateCreated = Date()
}
```

... and if you can also add a default `= Date()` as Leo Dabus suggested, so that when you are creating an `Item`, you don't need to provide it.

```
init(name: String, serialNumber: String?, valueInDollars: Int, someDateCreated: Date = Date()) {
    self.name = name /// set self.name to name
    self.valueInDollars = valueInDollars /// set self.valueInDollars to valueInDollars
    self.serialNumber = serialNumber /// set self.serialNumber to serialNumber
    self.dateCreated = someDateCreated /// set self.name to someDateCreated
}

/// --- usage ---
let someItem = Item(
    name: "Apple",
    serialNumber: "qwerty"
    valueInDollars: 123
)

/// you could still pass in a date if you want
let someOtherItem = Item(
    name: "Peach",
    serialNumber: "asdfg"
    valueInDollars: 99,
    someDateCreated: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 12312313)
)
```

Comment: you probably meant `init(name: String, serialNumber: String?, valueInDollars: Int, someDateCreated: Date = Date()) {` in your last example. Btw I would name it `dateCreated` as well and declare all properties as constants. If you ever need to edit them better to create a new object.